# Create DockerFile from repository

Tags: docker, github, build, dockerfile

I dont know if it's possible to create a DockerFile from an existing private repository. I created a container and installed an configured the server (i dont remember all the commands), so now I want it to be syncronized with my GitHub account so whenever I push in the branch it updates the changes in the image as well.
For the automatic builds it says that I need a DockerFile but I never created one. Is there an option to automatically create a dockerfile from an exisitng image/container. Using the docker history command doesnt help much because I made the server configurations using docker exec.
Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want to automate build process, explore Jenkins. never tried but I think it would solve your first problem as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start over.  Docker doesn't remember the commands you ran inside the container either, so it has no way to reconstruct the Dockerfile.  In any case, running `docker build` will always start from a clean environment, so it's helpful to build your Dockerfile without a bunch of manual installations.

For most languages you can probably easily find a sample Dockerfile by just looking for one.  Most of these are a pretty generic form: start `FROM` an appropriate base image, install OS dependencies, install library dependencies, `COPY` the application in, build it, and set runtime metadata like `CMD`.  You might be able to use one unmodified for popular platforms, since it's a little unusual to mention specific files other than the one that lists your dependencies (Node's `package.json`, Python's `requirements.txt`, ...).

You can also build up a Dockerfile by hand fairly easily.  Your secret weapon here is Docker layer caching: if you re-run `docker build` and nothing has changed up to and including the current line, Docker will skip over it and use the result from the last build.  You can fairly easily `docker system prune` to get rid of the extra images that got creating during the building process.  So a more incremental process can look like:

- Start `FROM` an appropriate base image
- If you want to run some command, add a `RUN` line and re-run `docker build`; do not `docker exec` or try to modify things in place
- If that went wrong in an obvious way, modify the `RUN` line and re-run `docker build`
- If it goes wrong in a non-obvious way, add "debugging printf" lines `RUN ls -lrt`; or `docker build` prints out 12-digit hex image IDs as it goes along, so `docker run --rm -it 0123456789ab /bin/sh` to get a shell to poke around the result of a given step
- When you're done, commit the resulting `Dockerfile` to source control

This is probably very similar to the process you did already, except instead of `docker exec`ing a series of commands, you're writing them down in the `Dockerfile` and building images.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get the exact question but here an example for multi stage docker build (build is dockerized itself) + a temp dependency stage (better layer cleanup) for a typescript example based on existing node.js images.

```
FROM node:12 AS build        # this could be ANY base image you want.
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .npmrc ./
RUN npm i
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM node:12 AS deps
WORKDIR /app
COPY .npmrc .
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=production

FROM  node:12-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules/ ./node_modules/
COPY --from=build /app/package.json .
COPY --from=build /app/build/src/ ./
COPY --from=build /app/build/config/ ./config/
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```